# Can't reboot with systemctl

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I'm running openbox, and I'm trying to reboot with systemctl, but I got the following error message:

```
%> systemctl reboot
Failed to issue method call: Unix process subject does not have uid set
Failed to issue method call: Access denied
```

From the output of strace, it is reading the session file,

`open("/run/systemd/sessions/2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4`

And I do have a line `UID=1000` in that file.

So I don't get it now, any ideas?

**EDIT**

Output of `loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID`

```
Id=1
Timestamp=Sun 2013-09-01 07:36:33 CST
TimestampMonotonic=14829938
DefaultControlGroup=systemd:/user/1000.user/1.session
VTNr=3
TTY=tty3
Remote=no
Service=login
Leader=1052
Audit=1
Type=tty
Class=user
Active=yes
State=active
KillProcesses=no
IdleHint=yes
IdleSinceHint=1377992182133333
IdleSinceHintMonotonic=3145123
Name=XX
```

Comment: Will `reboot` not suffice? Listing the OS would be nice.

Comment: @Tim Updated, running Arch

Comment: As I said in my last answer on this subject; you need to ensure you have an active logind session.

Comment: Hi @jasonwryan how can I verify that?

Comment: The output of `loginctl show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID`.

Comment: @jasonwryan attached

Comment: Session looks good; do you have `polkit` installed? See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/General_Troubleshooting#Session_permissions

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the following.

1. **Solution for Ubuntu** 
   **Pull Image command:**

   ```
   docker run -d --name Linuxamination --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-ubuntu:20.04
   ```

   **Log into the Container:**

   ```
   docker exec -it Linuxamination bash
   ```
2. **Solution for CentOS** 
   **Pull Image command:**

   ```
   docker run -d --name linuxaminationC8 --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro alekseychudov/centos8-systemd
   ```

   **Log into the Container:**

   ```
   docker exec -it linuxaminationC8 bash
   ```
3. **Solution for Debian** 
   **Pull Image command:**

   ```
   sudo docker run -d --name systemd-debian --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-debian:11
   ```

   **Log into the Container:**

   ```
   sudo docker exec -it systemd-debian bash
   ```
4. **Solution for Fedora** 
   **Pull Image command:**

   ```
   sudo docker run -d --name systemd-fedora --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro jrei/systemd-fedora
   ```

   **Log into the Container:**

   ```
   sudo docker exec -it systemd-fedora bash
   ```
5. **Solution for Red Hat Linux** 
   **Pull Image command:**

   ```
   sudo docker run -d --name linuxamination --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi-init:8.1
   ```

   **Log into the Container:**

   ```
   sudo docker exec -it linuxamination bash
   ```
6. **Solution for AlmaLinux** 
   **Pull Image command:**

   ```
   sudo docker run -d --name almalinuxamination --privileged -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro almalinux/8-init
   ```

   **Log into the Container:**

   ```
   sudo docker exec -it almalinuxamination bash
   ```

Comment: Please don't use non-ASCII versions of ASCII characters.